# CakePHP: How to show the same query data in all my views, directly in the layout file

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm creating a website with CakePHP; the problem now is that I want to show in the website footer (that will be visible on all the pages), the result of a query (e.g. "Most popular products").

***What is the correct way with CakePHP to achieve this?***

At the moment I created a `mostPopularList()` in my Product controller and a `most-popular-list.ctp` view that only outputs an `<ul>` list, thinking that then I could include the output of this file in my layout (`default.ctp`), but I didn't find the CakePHP way to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a view cell or call the query in the AppControllers beforeRender() callback and set it there to the view. Taken from the documentation:

> View cells are small mini-controllers that can invoke view logic and render out templates. They provide a light-weight modular replacement to requestAction(). The idea of cells is borrowed from cells in Ruby, where they fulfill a similar role and purpose.

- [View Cells](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html)
- [Controller::beforeRender()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_beforeRender)

If this is needed on really every single page I would probably go for the beforeRender() callback, easy to do and change globally.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I learned something new but indispensable! I tried both methods and they worked :) At last I chose to use a Cell in order to keep everything more clean.